# PHP OOP return into variable itself

Tags: php, function, oop, return

I need something simillar to `return` but "pointing inside". Let's say I have class:

```
class A {
  [...]
  public function say_hello() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
}
```

Is there any way to use return value into the object variable itself like:

instead of

```
$object = new A;
$object = $object->say_hello(); // $object has value 'Hello'
```

simply

```
$object = new A;
$object->say_hello(); // $object has value 'Hello'
```

I hope it's understandable.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

I wanna use it in situations when I need to call one class on another like:

```
class A {
  [...]
  public function call class B() {
    return new B();
  }
}
```

To have in the end saved in variable object of class B (C, D, etc.) instead of A.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: The first method `$object = $object->say_hell();` overwrites the previous `$object` to make it a string of `Hello`, while the second method - `$object->say_hello();` will return the `Hello` string, but not be assigned to anything.... so as Riz has said, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want situation in the last code block to variable $object change to "automatically" become its return value (without rewriting like `$object = $object->say_hello();`)

Comment: @Gomi Really don't know why you want to do that, but just pass the object it self by reference: `class A {

  public function say_hello(&$object) {
    $object = 'Hello';
  }
}

 $o = new A;
 $o->say_hello($o);
 var_dump($o);`

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a good reason for wanting to do this, but you could do something similar where you could easily access the last returned value:

```
class A
{
    private static $last_returned;
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return self::$last_returned;
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        self::$last_returned = call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);
        return self::$last_returned; 
    }
    private function say_hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}

$object = new A;
$object->say_hello();
echo $object(); //"hello";
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you. I wanna use it primarly in situations when I call one class from another.